# Retrieve a class with DOMDocument php

Tags: php, domdocument

I'm novice with php, i tried with every hint i found on internet but i didn't find how to get the content of the class "schmsg1":

```
<div class="space3"></div>
<div class="subtitle">Direction&nbsp;<b class="bwhite">Val de Fontenay RER</b></div>
<div class="bg1">&gt;&nbsp;Val de Fontenay</div>
<div class="schmsg1"><b>3 mn</b></div>
<div class="bg3">
```

Comment: Learn about xpath: http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/  , and you will be able to find every element inside a page, e.g. by an attribute(`like class`)

Answer (score 0):

It is not PHP issue! You can easily make clientside code (Using Javascript) that reads the text contents of that class, then using ajax you can send it to a php script to deal with it. I recommend Jquery to you.